# Android custom FragmentDialog error

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to do a custom DialogFragment in Android with a Spinner and two EditText, but I'm getting an error when I open the Dialog.
This is my DialogFragment class that is embeded into the activity:

```
public static class DialogListaPeces extends DialogFragment {

        private NuevaCaptura actividad;
        private Spinner spinner;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            actividad = (NuevaCaptura) getActivity();

            LayoutInflater inflater = actividad.getLayoutInflater();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(actividad);
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_specimen, null));

            SQLiteDatabase database = actividad.db.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, nombre FROM Peces", null);
            spinner = (Spinner) actividad.findViewById(R.id.spPeces_new_specimen);
            spinner.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(actividad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, c, new String[] { "nombre" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, SimpleCursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION));

            c.close();
            database.close();

            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int pez = (int) spinner.getSelectedItemId();
                    float longitud = Float.parseFloat(((EditText) actividad.findViewById(R.id.etLongitud_new_specimen)).getText().toString());
                    float peso = Float.parseFloat(((EditText) actividad.findViewById(R.id.etPeso_new_specimen)).getText().toString());
                    actividad.ejemplares.add(new Ejemplar(new Pez(pez), longitud, peso));
                    actividad.llenarListaEjemplares();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DialogListaPeces.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });

            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

and the error I'm getting:

```
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at com.ssoomm.pesca.NuevaCaptura$DialogListaPeces.onCreateDialog(NuevaCaptura.java:596)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:253)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
06-23 13:30:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(26186):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `NuevaCaptura.java` at line 596. This is where the `NullPointerException` takes place. Check your veriables there and make sure they are not `null`.

If you need help with that, you should tell as which is that line in the pasted code.

Comment: this line is where I call to the setAdapter method of the spinner, and nothing should be null at this point ;)